# How would I make something look at the nearest object with a specific tag, in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new, not sure if this is a dumb question.

I want to make something look at the nearest object with a specific tag.

I tried this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TowerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject.Enemy

    // Update is called once per frame
    Void; Update
        transform.LookAt(GameObject.Enemy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find object with this code

```
GameObject[] gos;
gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
```

and you can find nearest object with this method

```
Transform GetClosestEnemy(Transform[] enemies)
{
Transform tMin = null;
float minDist = Mathf.Infinity;
Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;
foreach (Transform t in enemies)
{
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(t.position, currentPos);
    if (dist < minDist)
    {
        tMin = t;
        minDist = dist;
    }
}
return tMin;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, have a very great day!